# How to get JSON data through ajax in jPut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I found a useful jQuery plugin for appending `JSON` data to `HTML` contents in an easy way in this link [Jput plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/jput)

But I would like to know how it is possible to send and get json data thorugh ajax ?
Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see for more details http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//jPut Code
$('#list_div').jPut({
   ajax_url:'data.json', //json url
   ajax_data:data,            //data that you want to send
   name:'list'
});
```

Please download & go through the docs and samples

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$.getJSON({
  url: "test.php",
  data:data,

 success:function(response){


        $('#list_div').jPut({
            jsonData:data,  //json
            name:'list'     //jPut name
        },
});
```

Here test.php should return a json data

Answer (score 2):

For recieving from server

`$.getJSON("sender_url",function(jsond){`

```
  `alert(JSON.stringify(jsond));`
```

`});`

> OR

`$.post("sender_url",{},function(response){`

```
  `var jsond=$.parseJSON(response);`

  `alert(JSON.stringify(jsond));`
```

`});`

for sending from client

`var json=[{"id":1,"name":"name1"}{"id":2,"name":"name2"}{"id":3,"name":"name3"}];`

`$.post("target_url",json,function(reply){`

```
  `alert(reply);
```

`})`

Example: target.php

`<?php`

`print_r($_POST);`

`?>`

Comment: this thing I know,but I want to append this jSON data to multiple div attributes.So,in normail ajax request,I have to use for loops for that which is clumsy,but I heard that in jput,we don't have to use loop and thereby we can reduce the data traffic .. Anyway thanks for reply.

Comment: @VaisakhPc: how come looping will increase  data traffic?? its happening on the client side right?